# NoReverseMatch when referencing ModelViewSet and DefaultRouter URLs

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, routes

I am using [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/), and am having difficulty using `reverse` to resolve URLs defined in `ModelViewSet`—which I imagine works the same way with `ViewSet`. I've tried using the URL patterns [described here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage), but I still get a `NoReverseMatch` error. I started a new project with app `places` to troubleshoot, but the issue persists. In *settings.py*, I have added `places` and `rest_framework` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and made no other changes.

*project urls.py*

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import re_path, include

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^v1/', include(('places.urls', 'places'))),
    re_path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

*`places` app urls.py*

```py
from django.urls import re_path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register('places', views.PlaceViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

*models.py*

```py
from django.db import models


class Place(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

*tests.py*

```py
from django.urls import reverse

from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from .models import *


class TestPlaces(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Place.objects.create(title='Manhattan Mansion')

    def test_list(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('place-list'))
```

*Traceback*

```py
(.env) $ ./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_list (places.tests.TestPlaces)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matt/test/places/tests.py", line 12, in test_list
    response = self.client.get(reverse('place-list'))
  File "/home/matt/test/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/matt/test/.env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'place-list' not found. 'place-list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I even tried specifying the basename when registering to the app router.

```py
router.register('places', views.PlaceViewSet, basename='place')
```

What can I do to correct this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('place-list'))
```

to

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('places-list'))
```

Whenever you register your APIs as `places` in your urls without naming it's router.

If the above solution does not solve your problem use this one (since you've used name space in your urls and the default router name is `places`):

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('places:places-list'))
```

Comment: Using the `places` namespace helped, even though I didn't explicitly define it. Thanks!